# Jboss Server is running in standalone mode, but server groups have been defined

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jboss6.x

Getting following error while deploying EAR to Jboss via `jboss-as-maven-plugin` plugin.

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.7.Final:deploy
>   (default-cli) on project xxx: Server is running in
>   standalone mode, but server groups have been defined.

**Jboss is running in standalone mode.**

I have deleted all server-groups from `domain.xml` manually, and even tried to remove them with `jboss-cli` and no `server-groups` are finally there in `domain.xml`

Comment: It looks like the server itself is running in standalone mode. How was the server started?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins yes the server is running in standalone mode. I need to use it in standalone mode only. the problem is server groups defined which is coming after removing server -groups from jboss-cli

Comment: If you're running standalone the `domain.xml` will not be used at all. The error is saying there is a `<domain/>` configuration in your `jboss-as-maven-plugin` configuration.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins thanks for response . But, i'm not having any plugin related configuration in my pom.xml. Directly running the command as `mvn jboss-as:deploy`.

Comment: What version of JBoss AS or JBoss EAP are you using? The only way that error should be thrown is if the `<domain><server-group>something</server-group></domain>` is in the `jboss-as-maven-plugin` configuration. Check the parent pom maybe too. It could be getting inherited.